# Write data to Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, windows-10-desktop

I would like to create a simple app that writes data to the windows 10 taskbar, similar to the example below. Any idea how I would do this? Preferably, I could update the string every minute or so.

[image: data in taskbar]

Comment: which project type UWP or legacy desktop app?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#deskbands